# How to Unpivot the data from a single row into multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench, heidisql

1. Requirement 1:

   - TO UNPIVOT the given data (as shown below) in a row into multiple rows (should exclude the null values) as shown in Output required.
   - The GRADES column can have multiple values (the code has to loop until the complete set is split or unpivoted.

- Source:

| ID | GRADES |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [A,B,C,C,D] |
| 456 | [A,,D] |

- Output required:

| ID | GRADES |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | B |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | D |
| 456 | A |
| 456 | D |

2. Requirement 2:

   - Use the unpivoted data (as shown below) & select only the distinct records from them and pivot them back to load into a different table. as shown in Output required.

- Source:

| ID | GRADES |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A |
| 123 | B |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | C |
| 123 | D |
| 456 | A |
| 456 | D |

- Output required:

| ID | GRADES |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [A,B,C,D] |
| 456 | [A,D] |

I tried to create a procedure using substring, locate, instr to split the values and concat them back but unable to achieve the required output. Currently stuck with the logic.

Comment: plead read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and next time try to normalize your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Requirement 1:

```
-- Assuming you have a table called 'source' with columns 'ID' and 'GRADES'

-- Create a temporary table to hold the unpivoted data
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_unpivoted_data (
  ID INT,
  GRADE CHAR(1)
);

-- Unpivot the data from the 'source' table
INSERT INTO temp_unpivoted_data (ID, GRADE)
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GRADES, ',', n), ',', -1) AS GRADE
FROM source
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 -- Add more if needed
) AS numbers
ON CHAR_LENGTH(GRADES) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(GRADES, ',', '')) >= n - 1
WHERE GRADES <> '';

-- Retrieve the unpivoted data
SELECT ID, GRADE
FROM temp_unpivoted_data;
```

For Requirement 2:

```
-- Create a temporary table to hold the distinct pivoted data
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_pivoted_data (
  ID INT,
  GRADES VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Pivot the data from the 'temp_unpivoted_data' table
INSERT INTO temp_pivoted_data (ID, GRADES)
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT GRADE ORDER BY GRADE SEPARATOR ',') AS GRADES
FROM temp_unpivoted_data
GROUP BY ID;

-- Retrieve the pivoted data
SELECT ID, GRADES
FROM temp_pivoted_data;
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked for the current requirement.